# Combine character vectors and use the negative of that vector to put rows or columns to zero

Tags: r, vector, character

I have a dataframe and two character vectors which have certain columns names of that dataframe, say:

```
    dat <- read.table(
  text = "A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
  A   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0
  B   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
  C   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
  D   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
  E   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
  F   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
  G   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
  H   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
  I   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
  J   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0",
  header = TRUE
)

charvec1 <- c("A","C","E")
charvec2 <- c("I","J","D")
```

I would like to put the two character vectors together and put rows and columns of the data frame which are not in that new vector to zero.

I tried to do the following without much success:

```
# put the two character vectors together
charvec3 <- c(t(outer(charvec1 , charvec2 , paste)))

# use the character vectors to put the column names which are not mentioned to zero
dat[-charvec3,] <- 0 # Row will be set to zero
dat[,-charvec3] <- 0 # Column will be set to zero,
```

Can someone explain to me how to do this properly?

Comment: Try with `setdiff(rownames(dat), charvec3))` and `setdiff(colnames(dat), charvec3)`

Comment: Sample data throws an error

Comment: @RichScriven , I noticed, any idea why:S I just added a few columns compared to another example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
charvec <- c(charvec1, charvec2)
dat[, !colnames(dat) %in% charvec] <- 0
dat[!rownames(dat) %in% charvec, ] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks @bbecker! But this will set the wrong rows/columns to zero if I am correct right?